# Post and Category structure for multiple types with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, filter, ruby-on-rails-5, categories

I have a post table and I need to be able to assign multiple filters to it, such as

**Style: 
Type:
Category:**

I don't want to create separate tables for each that would over complicate everything. I was thinking to have one **category** table and maybe create entries with initials like

Table [Category]

- cat-website
- cat-ios
- style-dark
- style-simple
- type-portfolio
- ...

so I could keep all in 1 table and strip cat/style/type part when I display the filters and I will end up having only 1 table. Plus it may help to make multiple selections (I hope) easier such as ***www.website.com/posts?category=cat1+cat18+cat53***

---

**Does this approach make sense at all?**

Comment: You can use polymorphic associations for this approach http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: @ZiaQamar hmm, never heard of that one. Checking it out. thank you!

Comment: There are a few ways to do it. I would personally add Boolean fields to my Posts table. Because I don't see how you would link that category table to the post table.. there no parent/child here..

Answer (score 0):

I would **not** recommend the approach you outline. Having to do that stripping cat/style/type sounds pure yuck.

Why not use something like [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)? I am not affiliated with the gem, but use it in all of my projects and find it very useful for categorizing and filtering.

Comment: actually, I'm currently using it. I find it a bit hard to manage with people entering silly tags, having all the mess, etc.. I'm sure there are better ways to manage it with limiting tags, probably giving preset tags for users to select so on, but so far my experience with it wasnt very nice, and I wanted to move away from it.

Comment: Sure, there are loads of easy ways to limit tags to only 'acceptable' tags. But, I get it. Sometimes one wishes to skin a cat which has previously been done so.